# How does dynamodb handle records with hashKey as undefined

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I would like to create a global index for a dynamodb table. Most of records in the table have 'undefined' value for the global index's hashKey. How does dynamodb partition these records with 'undefined' hashKey? I only query the global index using non-undefined hashKey value. I am wondering if these 'undefined' hashKey records may hurt the query performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by undefined you mean they have the actual string value of "undefined" they will be in the index and this can hurt performance by potentially creating a hot shard.

However, if by undefined you mean these attributes do not have any values associated with them then this will end up creating what is called a sparse index.  Having a sparse index means these items will not be in the GSI at all and this will be good for performance because writes to objects that lack these attributes will not requires writes to the GSI.

Sparse indexes are a powerful feature of DynamoDB as it provides another way to get access to items.  For example, having a sparse index means it can have substantially fewer records making scans of the GSI practical for some use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sparse Index is exactly what I need.

Comment: You can read more about Sparse Indexes from the AWS documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForGSI.html#GuidelinesForGSI.SparseIndexes